# SQL to Search for rownum 1 if priority designation of 1 is not found

Tags: sql, rownum, peoplesoft-app-engine

In a lengthy insert SQL statement, need to select whatever ship_to_cust_id is in first row...ONLY IF...there is no PRIORITY 1 row. These are simplified versions of the SQL.  How do I combine, so it looks for priority 1 first, and only then selects the first row's ship_to_cust_id if no priority 1 row is found?  These are abbreviated SQL that work to pull both; how to merge into one statement?

```
SELECT 
    s.cust_id, s.ship_to_cust_id, s.sldto_priority_nbr
FROM 
    sysadm.ps_cust_shipto s, sysadm.PS_CUST_BILLTO b
WHERE 
    b.setid = 'SHARE' 
    AND b.cust_id = '90677671'
    AND b.setid = s.setid 
    AND b.cust_id = s.cust_id 
    AND s.ship_to_cust_id IN (SELECT x.ship_to_cust_id 
                              FROM sysadm.ps_cust_shipto x
                              WHERE x.sldto_priority_nbr = 1 
                                AND x.cust_id = b.cust_id)

SELECT 
    s.cust_id, s.ship_to_cust_id, s.sldto_priority_nbr
FROM 
    sysadm.ps_cust_shipto s, sysadm.PS_CUST_BILLTO b
WHERE 
    b.setid = 'SHARE' 
    AND b.cust_id = '90677671'
    AND b.setid = s.setid 
    AND b.cust_id = s.cust_id 
    AND s.ship_to_cust_id IN (SELECT y.ship_to_cust_id 
                              FROM sysadm.ps_cust_shipto y
                              WHERE rownum = 1 
                                AND y.cust_id = b.cust_id)
```

Here is sample input data on the table we need to extract from for this particular value. This one has Priority 1, but sometimes it is missing.

`SETID  CUST_ID SHIP_TO_CUST_ID  SLDTO_PRIORITY_NBR  LAST_OPRID`
`SHARE   90677671    114369323         2            JENNIFERBRYAN`
`SHARE   90677671    114479768         3            JENNIFERBRYAN`
`SHARE   90677671    90677695          1             TARAARROYO`

I have tried using CASE logic, since if the condition is satisfied re the priority, it would not evaluate further. CASE works that way to terminate once a condition is satisfied.

But I have tried many versions and nothing works. I read somewhere that when CASE is used in a select, it can only do equal/not-equal evaluations; not conditional logic, so that might be the problem.

This code will be in a PeopleSoft App Engine. It is part of a long insert statement's conditional logic, so not as simple as the logic presented. However, above addresses the main components...but I need to combine the logic re priority and rownum. If a priority 1 row is found, use that ship_to_cust_id; we don't need to worry about rownum in that case.  But if no priority 1, then we can use the ship_to_cust_id from the first row.

Comment: I saw something like this in the "related questions," and it did not work.  Any tinkering suggestions?                                                                                                                      
   `SELECT from xxxx where... AND b.setid = s.setid AND b.cust_id = s.cust_id 
  and s.ship_to_cust_id in 
(if EXISTS (SELECT y.ship_to_cust_id FROM sysadm.ps_cust_shipto y where y.cust_id = b.cust_id)
BEGIN
   SELECT y.ship_to_cust_id where y.sldto_priority_nbr = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT y.ship_to_cust_id where rownum = 1
END)`

Comment: Still hoping for suggestions.  Your input would be greatly appreciated!  Okie4ever.